# What should I do if I get activation error on Xbox UWP app and there is nothing useful in the error message?

Tags: c++, uwp, xbox-one, c++-winrt

I got xbox system update push recently on dev mode. My program winrtcpp program stops working, while other c++/cx program does still run on the xbox. In the meantime, I did not change my code or relevant dependencies. And the program is running correctly on PC.

Is there a general strategy for solving this kind of windows app activation problem.

Error message: 
"unable to activate Windows.Store.app...The process started, but the activation request failed with error 'The app didn't start.'"

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/frequently-asked-questions

Why aren't my games and apps working?

If your games and apps aren't working, or if you don't have access to the store or to Live services, you are probably running in Developer Mode. To figure out which mode you're currently in, press the Home button on your controller. If this takes you to Dev Home instead of the retail Home experience, you're in Developer Mode. If you want to play games, you can open Dev Home and switch back to Retail Mode by using the Leave developer mode button.